# converting C style unicode escapes to htmlentities

Tags: php, regex, unicode, html-entities

I want to change every `C` style `unicode` char into `html` entity. I've written this function to do that:

```
function ununicode($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', '&#x$1;', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

it works good, *but* ignores second character in sth like that `\u00f6\u00df`. ie it will produce: `&#x00f6;\u00df`

whats wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `g` flag (which allows more than one replacement per line), so that it's this:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/ig', '&#x$1;', $text);
```

#### Edit:

Your code as written seems to work for me:

```
php > $text = "\u00f6\u00df";
php > print $text;
\u00f6\u00df
php > $text2 = preg_replace('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', '&#x$1;', $text);
php > print $text2;
&#x00f6;&#x00df;
```

Comment: Ah, right, PHP's preg implementation is non-standard in that it effectively always has /g on. But, as I edited my answer to reflect, your existing code seems to be working fine, at least with your example.